# What is the the best framework to use for Single Page Applications

Tags: css, html

Im very new to programming and I'm wondering if someone can point me in the direction of how to make a website show 3 images that represent products and instead of redirecting me to another page but instead stay on the current page and show information about that product which can lead to a purchase.

I'd like to be able to build a SPA, but I'm in the early stages of learning HTML, Css and Javascript. What are the best framework to start using if i want to create a information website with just contact info, about me sections and so on.

Comment: Is Angular what you need? Or AJAX, which returns data without redirecting or reloading the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term what you are searching is Single-Page Applications (SPAs) which are Web apps that load a single HTML page and dynamically update that page as the user interacts with the app.

To have smooth scroll and other animation effects, you need to write JavaScript that can run be executed in the client side. I strongly recommend you to use a framework which is specifically designed to develop client side web applications such as Angular, Jquery. There are lot of options and I can't just specify all of them nor recommend specific one without knowing your actual requirements.

Do a basic research on Single-Page Applications, client side web applications in Internet, you will find lot of frameworks and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to use single page application nowadays is using frameworks like bootstrap. You could use their ready functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

The "Dodo" framework is a lightweight JavaScript framework designed for building dynamic and reactive web applications. With its focus on simplicity and ease of use, Dodo provides developers with a straightforward yet powerful tool for creating modern web applications. It offers a Model-View-Controller (MVC) structure, prioritizing fast development, and efficient execution while avoiding the complexities of TypeScript, making it an attractive choice for those seeking an accessible framework.

http://dodo.mikosoft.info